# kotlin: how can I call function from object expression

Tags: kotlin

I have such code:

```
// foo.kt
fun bar() {
    val foo = object {
        fun zzz() {
            println()
        }
    }

    foo.zzz()
}
```

And I use `kotlinc foo.kt` to compile the kotlin code. I got 'FooKt.class' and 'FooKt$bar$foo$1.class' as result.
And then I decompile the 'FooKt.class' file to discover the java code, it is like this(by jd-gui):

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import kotlin.Metadata;

@Metadata(mv={1, 1, 6}, bv={1, 0, 1}, k=2, d1={"\000\006\n\000\n\002\020\002\032\006\020\000\032\0020\001"}, d2={"bar", ""})
public final class MainKt
{
  public static final void bar()
  {
    Object foo = new Object()
    {
      public final void zzz()
      {
        System.out.println();
      }
    };
    foo.zzz();        // You can NOT do this in java world. But kotlin can do. Why?
  }
}
```

I'm curious about the java code above. If you paste the code to any ide and compile(javac), there will be an error: `zzz unresolved`.
The error above say that you can't call any custom function from a `new Object()` even you extend it.
Now is the question: Kotlin generated such error code but all seems ok, why?

Comment: Please show decompiled FooKt$bar$foo$1.class

Answer (score 0):

This is because Kotlin create an extra class extending from object `FooKt$bar$foo$1.class`. You can use anonymous objects always than you aren't exposing it outer the scope.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html